# How can I remove items ahead of the current index in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am trying to remove items from an array that are ahead of the current index of another array.

For example I have this:

```js
const d = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"];
const scenarioIndex = 1

const solution = () => {
  return // return the solution here
};
```

In that case the result must be `["one"]`

I do always have to return the current and previous items.

If `const scenarioIndex = 2` it must return `["one", "two"]`

I tried a couple of things with no success and this code seems to be doing the opposite of what I need => https://codesandbox.io/s/javascript-forked-gjdoy?file=/index.js:0-263

```js
const d = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"];
const scenarioIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 0;

const solution = () => {
  console.log(scenarioIndex);
  return d.splice(scenarioIndex + 1, d.length - scenarioIndex);
};

console.log(solution());
```

Comment: so start from zero? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The splice method mutates the original array so just return it:

```js
const d = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"];
const scenarioIndex = 1

const solution = (arr, index) => (arr.splice(index), arr);

console.log('Splice solution:', solution(d, scenarioIndex));
console.log('Original array:', d);
```

If you don't want to mutate the original array, prefer using [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```js
const d = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"];
const scenarioIndex = 1

const solution = (arr, index) => arr.slice(0, index);

console.log('Slice solution:', solution(d, scenarioIndex));
console.log('Original array:', d);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the splice method. Start from zero and pass the index as second param.

```
d.splice(0, scenarioIndex);
```

If you don't want to mutate the existing array then

```
[...d].splice(0, scenarioIndex);
```

Comment: Text says `slice` code says `splice` - which did you mean to use?

Comment: Sorry about that. I meant splice.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you simply want to splice from index 0 to your `scenarioIndex`

```js
const d = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"];
const scenarioIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 0;

const solution = () => {
  console.log(scenarioIndex);
  return d.splice(0, scenarioIndex);
};

console.log(solution());
```